# Heroku deployment API rate limit exceeded

Tags: django, heroku

I have one django project and try to deploy it on heroku server. There is one function in the project to save the processed data into sql db by for loop. It's ok for the first loop, but in the second loop, There is the error to show "list index out of range". I try to adjust the list so that if list length is not that long, the saving will be "NA". I just found that the last saving shows such text:{"error":"API rate limit exceeded","api-key":"54.204.136.114","count":"4","limit":"3"}
Is this problem due to the API query limit of heroku? When I apply such function in local server, the function is just fine. So, how could I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a free version of the heroku ? Which have only the max deploys of the 5 apps for free.

Comment: Yes, I only deploy one app. But it seems show that the api rate limit exceeded.

Comment: Yes. I have checked it. But I want to know how to overcome the limit. Should I set it up in dashboard of heroku?