# Django project deployment without API rate limit

Tags: django, server

Can I know if there is any free server for Django project deployment without API rate limit?

Comment: Maybe https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ . But to be honest, if you want to run something for production, you should purchase a hosting.

Comment: Thx! I tried heroku before but it seems that it has api rate limit as the next question I asked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909474/heroku-deployment-api-rate-limit-exceeded/53909761?noredirect=1#comment94664102_53909761). So pythonanywhere could work?